# Numeric input validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am doing validation on an input `type='text'` element.  I have wired up the `paste` and the `keydown` events to trap the input and restrict it to just numbers. The `keydown` seems to work without a hitch, however, I could not seem to get any of the browsers to actually NOT PASTE the text into the field (I see that there is a `beforepaste` event, which may be the ticket -- however it appears to not be supported by Firefox.  In the end, I resulted to just blanking out the input if the value was not a number.  This causes a momentary flicker, but seems to work.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?  Am I missing something?  Is there anyway to prevent the flicker? I know the HTML5 has a type='number', but I'm not ready to go there yet.

```
<input type="text" id="number" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        enableNumericOnlyEntry("#number");

        function enableNumericOnlyEntry(object) {
            $(object).bind('paste', numericOnlyPaste);
            $(object).bind('keydown', null, numericOnlyKeyDown);

            function numericOnlyPaste(event) {
                var inputText = "";
                var element = event.target;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var text = $(element).val();
                    if (isNaN(text)) {
                        $(element).val("")
                        return false;
                    }
                }, 0);
            }

            function numericOnlyKeyDown(event) {
                // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
                if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
                    // Allow: Ctrl+A/a
                    (event.keyCode == 65 || event.keyCode == 97) && (event.ctrlKey === true) ||
                    // Allow: Ctrl+C/c
                    (event.keyCode == 67 || event.keyCode == 99) && (event.ctrlKey === true) ||
                    // Allow: Ctrl+V/v
                    (event.keyCode == 86 || event.keyCode == 118) && (event.ctrlKey === true) ||
                    // Allow: Ctrl+X/x
                    (event.keyCode == 88 || event.keyCode == 120) && (event.ctrlKey === true) ||
                    // Allow: home, end, left, right
                    (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                    // let it happen, don't do anything
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                    if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Not many browsers support it yet, but HTML5 has a number type for input just like this.  You'll still need this for backwards compatibility, but at least you can take advantage of the newer features.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this project to create a field that is a masked edit box, you could remove the underscore to it also so it doesn't look like a masked edit.  Really easy to use: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

then you'd use something like $("#box").mask("9999999"); and your good to go, works great!

Answer (score 0):

HTML5's `<input type="number">` is really where you want to go with this. If you're working with browsers that support it (basically everything except Safari and old versions of IE), it does everything you want.

That said, why not register an [onpaste](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.onpaste) handler so you can reduce pasted content to just numbers after the user pastes?

Comment: Support for `type="number"` is a bit more choppy than that, currently: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number. Safari (desktop) does support it, but Firefox doesn't. Though, there is a [notable](https://github.com/h5bp/html5please/blob/master/posts/input-number.md) polyfill available.

Comment: he was trying options like that said the onpaste was making a flicker, and wanted something other than type='number', think the mask edit will be the best way to go for him, they work like a charm.